# JAVA: Empty values when passing to another class

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working on a program in which passing arrays to another class. However, when I try load the Class in which I passed a set of array values, there are no values in it. See my code:

**Menu.java**

```
public class Menu extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        private String[] menu;
        private Globals vars = new Globals();
        private DefaultTableModel grill;
        private DefaultTableModel seafoods;
        private DefaultTableModel rice;
        private DefaultTableModel drinks;
        private int menuCount;

        public Menu() {
            initComponents();
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            menuCount = vars.countMenu();
            menu = new String[menuCount];
            menu = vars.setMenu();
            grill = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            seafoods = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
            rice = (DefaultTableModel) jTable3.getModel();
            drinks = (DefaultTableModel) jTable4.getModel();

            /*** SOME CODES HERE ***/

            /*** item_name, item_code, item_qty, item_price are arrays ***/
            /*** I have already tested them and they have values ***/


            if (noValue > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please input quantity");
                return;
            }

            if (count == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Plese select some items");
                return;
            } else {
                Transaction trns = new Transaction();
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, count);
                trns.setSelectedItems(item_name, item_code, item_qty, item_price, count);
                trns.setVisible(true);
                //this.setVisible(false);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new Menu().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
```

**Transaction.java**

```
public class Transaction extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private String[] itemcode;
    private double[] qty;
    private double[] price;
    private String[] items;
    private String[] info;
    private static Scanner iRead;
    private int count;

    public Transaction() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        itemcode = new String[count];

        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        String header = "| Item Code | Item Name | Price | Quantity";
        listModel.addElement(header);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, count);

        lsItems.setModel(listModel);
    }
    public void setSelectedItems(String[] itm, String[] cd, double[] qnty, double[] prc, int itemCnt) {
        this.items = itm;
        this.itemcode = cd;
        this.qty = qnty;
        this.price = prc;
        this.count = itemCnt;
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass an array of values [`setSelectedItems()`] from `Menu` Class to `Transaction` class. However, When I load `Transaction` Class, no values received.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? It seems like you're expecting some model to be populated but all `setSelectedItems` does it set some member fields of the class.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Michael I am expecting values from Menu Class in which Transaction Class (jList)should be displayed. That's why I passed values from Menu to Transaction class with `setSelectedItems`. I used that `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, count);` to check if values are successfully passed.

Comment: Why do you have two jframes when all you do is show one jframe that shows another jframe? Please provide a MCVE so we could understand your problem.

Comment: It is not clear what happens to eg this.items after it has been set in setSelectedItems. Therefore it is practically impossible to help you with your question.